# How to resolve Jetty AbstractHandler not sending the request to the next

Tags: java, jetty, handler, jetty-9

I am working on a project where we are going to using Jetty AbstractHandler to intercept all the requests to do some validation.

Below is the basic handler declaration:

```
public class HandlerClass extends AbstractHandler
{
    @Override
    public void handle(String target, Request baseRequest, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws IOException, ServletException
    {
        String requestURI = request.getRequestURI();
        LOG.debug("Request Handler received");
        try
            {
                if (!getStatus())
                {
                    response.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
                    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN);
                    response.setCharacterEncoding(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());

                    ErrorBuilder errorBuilder = new ErrorBuilder();
                    Schema schema = errorBuilder.getErrorInstance(Status.FORBIDDEN.getStatusCode(), "forbidden", "Authorization failed", "Request not allowed.");
                    String responseData = new Gson().toJson(schema);
                    response.getOutputStream().print(responseData);
                    response.flushBuffer();
                    baseRequest.setHandled(true);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                System.out.print(e);
            }
    }
}
```

Below is the binding into jetty.xml:

```
<Set name="handler">
    <New id="Handlers" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection">
      <Set name="handlers">
       <Array type="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Handler">
         <Item>
           <New class="handlers.HandlerClass"/>
         </Item>
       </Array>
      </Set>
    </New>
  </Set>
```

I can see all the requests are intercepting inside the handler method but if `getStatus()` returning true then the requests are not going from the handler to the next.
If `getStatus()` returning false then I am able to see the error response as per my code.

I am not sure where I am doing wrong or what I configuration I missed due to which request is not going from the handler class in case of `getStatus()` returning true.

Note: "getStatus()" is a custom-defined method that is returning true or false wrt some conditions.

Comment: What is `getStatus()`?  That's not a method on Jetty's `AbstractHandler`.

Comment: @Joakim No that is a custom-defined method that is returning true or false wrt some conditions.

Answer (score 0):

When you call

```java
baseRequest.setHandled(true);
```

that means the request is handled, and subsequent handlers (regardless of where they show up in the handler tree) will not be called with that request.